# Scheduler Calendar datetime Picker time intervals

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datetimepicker

I need scheduler pop up datetime picker with one hour intervals. I tried this thing after changing outer Html of the popped input screen it will display data in correct way but their are issues in reading the selected data. It read wrong dates after i change the Popup. Please refer the attached images for more info. And want to define time range 8.00 am to 6.00 pm[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCHRW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the provided information it's not clear how exactly you are setting the corresponding option of the DateTimePicker, however the described scenario works as expected on my side - please check the example below:

http://dojo.telerik.com/inonu